# Convergence of series $\sum a_rb_r$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Assuming $\sum a^2_r$ and $\sum b^2_r$ converge, can we deduce that $\sum a_rb_r$ converges? It feels like we can, but how? Using Cauchy Criterion for convergence maybe?

Can you hint me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Schwarz_inequality#Rn).

Comment: Hint: expand $(a-b)^2\ge0$ and show $|ab|\le(1/2)(a^2+b^2)$. Then compare.

Comment: The method David Mitra suggested is more elementary than the Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2\sum_r|a_rb_r|\leqslant\sum_ra_r^2+\sum_rb_r^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to get $$\sum|a_rb_r|\le \sqrt{\sum a_r^2\sum b_r^2}$$ So the series is absolutely convergent and hence convergent.

Comment: Oops, sorry. correcting it.